# How to debug issues when adding packages to a meteor project

Tags: meteor

I installed meteor 1.8.1 yesterday.

And then i tried to install coffeescript.

just like this :

"meteor add coffeescript"

but error is like this :

Error: Could not get https://warehouse.meteor.com/builds/EXSxwGqYjjJKh3WMJ/1540998837302/9YEg39egQi/coffeescript-2.3.2_1-os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova.tgz; server returned [502]

Does any one solved this problem?

How would you go about debugging a problem like this?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or use a vpn

Comment: I've allowed myself to paraphrase your question to be more general and more useful to more people.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jankapunkt suggested, I would start debugging this at the network level:

- verify that you can `ping warehouse.meteor.com`
- run

  ```
  curl -i https://warehouse.meteor.com/builds/EXSxwGqYjjJKh3WMJ/1540998837302/9YEg39egQi/coffeescript-2.3.2_1-os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova.tgz
  ```

  and check for errors. There might be a more elaborate error description you can get this way rather than just the error code (502 in your case).